# Using spring ldapTemplate, how do i delete/unbind an LDAP entry?

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

How do I unbind an LDAP entry via Spring LdapTemplate?

I have an LDAP entry uid=johnsmith@example.com,objectClass=posixAccount. Not sure if it matters, but johnsmith@example.com is also a member of group1.

```
com  
  |
  +--example (dc=example,objectClass=organization)
       |
       +--groups (ou=groups,objectClass=organizationUnit)
       |    |
       |    +--group1 (cn=group1,objectClass=groupOfNames)
       |    +--group2 (cn=group2,objectClass=groupOfNames)
       |
       +--people (ou=people,objectClass=organizationUnit)
            |
            +--johnsmith@example.com (uid=johnsmith@example.com,objectClass=posixAccount)
            +--janesmith@example.com (uid=janesmith@example.com,objectClass=posixAccount)
```

**What I tried thus far:**

```
Name dn = new DistinguishedName();
dn.add("ou", "people");
dn.add("uid", "johnsmith@example.com");

ldapTemplate.unbind(dn);
```

But the LDAP entry is not deleted, even though no exception is thrown.

**I also tried recursive unbind:**

```
Name dn = new DistinguishedName();
dn.add("ou", "people");
dn.add("uid", "johnsmith@example.com");

ldapTemplate.unbind(dn, true);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception occurred in target VM: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'uid=johnsmith@example.com,ou=people'  org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'uid=johnsmith@example.com,ou=people'
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:174)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.deleteRecursively(LdapTemplate.java:1122)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$25.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:1083)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:807)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadWrite(LdapTemplate.java:802)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.doUnbindRecursively(LdapTemplate.java:1081)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.unbind(LdapTemplate.java:1044)
(etc....)
```

**Edit:
I found out the problem.
There was a typo in the uid, which is why the unbind didn't delete the LDAP entry...**

Comment: Try to add `dn.add("dc", "example")`. A distinguished name should have the full path.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried that but it doesn't work. Not sure if relevant, but ldapTemplate is autowired by Spring and initialized with an ldapContextSource which is initialized with the LDAP baseDN.

Comment: The statement should be before your `add`s since it is more significant unit. As for the LdapContextSource, it is important to have a authorized LDAP user to start the context with, but it depends on your LDAP server.

Comment: I think the ldapTemplate is set up correctly because I am able to succesfully create/bind an LDAP entry... it just fails when I try to delete/unbind...

Comment: Sorry I can't help more, but try doing the same thing with java's basic LDAP support. It might throw more specific exceptions you can investigate along the way.